# I'm having trouble with ngTableParams refreshing

Tags: angularjs, refresh, apply, ngtable

I can't seem to figure out the refresh.  I can get the intial load of the page, but when the function getActivity() is run it doesn't update the page.  At a loss.  Tried many different things but to no success.

This code below is being called from a factory

```
uaAppCommon.tableParams = function(data,sortFieldOrder){
        var table = new ngTableParams({
             //page: 1,            // show first page
             count: data.length,          // count per page
             sorting: sortFieldOrder
         }, {
            counts: [],  //hides page sizes
             total: data.length, // length of data
             getData: function($defer, params) {
                 // use build-in angular filter
                 var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                     $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) :
                                     data;
                 $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
             }
         });
        return table;
    };
```

This snippet is the calling function within the controller.

```
$scope.getActivity = function(numDays){
        appService.loadActivity(numDays)
        .then(function(response){
            var activity = appService.getActivity();
            $scope.activityTable = appCommon.tableParams(activity,{date: 'desc'});  
        });
    };
```

This is the HTML:

```
<table ng-table="activityTable" class="table" fixed-table-headers="scrollable-area">
                            <tr ng-repeat="act in $data">
                                <td data-title="'Date & Time'" sortable="'date'">
                                    {{act.date}}
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Activity'" sortable="'activity'">
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide plunker?
Can you check this line in your controller
**$scope.activityTable = appCommon.tableParams(activity,{date: 'desc'});** 
try replacing it with 
**$scope.activityTable = uappCommon.tableParams(activity,{date: 'desc'});**

and if that doesn't work reload your table **yourtablename.reload()** after your function gets called.